# Navigating outside of dir into a different directory in primefaces

Tags: jsf, path, facelets, templating

I am using templates with primefaces and I can't seem to get this right. I keep getting a `500 error`. I am basically trying to navigate from `createorder.xhtml` to `WEB-INF/templates/fullpagetemplate.xhtml`.

The path I have now in the createorder.xhtml is:

```
template="/WEB-INF/templates/fullpagetemplate.jsf"
```

I keep getting an exception:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException: /order/createorder.xhtml @7,53 <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/fullpagetemplate.jsf"> Invalid path : /WEB-INF/templates/fullpagetemplate.jsf
```

---

**Screenshot of file structure:**

[image: Hello]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go up one directory first before navigating to the `WEB-INF` directory by preceding your file path with `..` like this:

```
template="../WEB-INF/templates/fullpagetemplate.jsf"
```